# Can't send PUT Request because of Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: javascript, json, nginx, request, cors

I know, that this is a really common topic and I already have checked many of the questions on stackoverflow. But my case is a kind of different, because I don't get the problem. Basically, I know how to handle CORS, and I already tried many solutions.

Let me explain the situation:

My setup is an Ionic project (on localhost), that sends via http request an PUT to my self hosted Directus Headless-CMS. GET and POST work perfectly.
When I try the request via Postman, it works very well. I know that Postman sends automatically additional headers within its request. I tried to add them in my code as well, but still the same respone message.

This is my response code snippet within Ionic

```
  var jsonbody = {};
  jsonbody['german'] = "lorem ipsum";
  jsonbody['turoyo'] = "lorem ipsum";
  jsonbody['description'] = "lorem ipsum";
  console.log(jsonbody);

  this.http.put('http://example.com/api/1.1/tables/translation/rows/1?access_token=myaccesstoken', jsonbody, {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        //foo
      },
      (error) => {
        //bar
      },
      () => {
        //foobar
      }
    );
```

In my browser console I get this message after trying the request:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/1.1/tables/translation/rows/1?access_token=myaccesstoken. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

In Postman, it works like a breeze. Look

[image]

You also have the possibility in Postman to generate the according code snippet for that request. In this case it's:

[image]

Anybody an idea what I did wrong? Maybe I just missed a detail. I also tried to add headers to my nginx sites-enabled configuration. But that didn't make a difference. But that makes no sense to me, because Postman did send the request.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to configure your server to handle the pre-flight and return `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT`

Comment: If you can run both the local page and the API on same domain name then the error wont occur, else you need to setup CORS in nginx

Comment: Like I said: It works, when I do the request with Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/). That means the server can handle the request. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added CORS settings to your `/[directus]/api/.htaccess` file?

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried this solution and it works:

https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration/

I just put the CORS statements into my locations rule.

Anyways very strange to me, that this worked with the tool I mentioned.